# Delete columns from matrix according to its index

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I have a two-dimensional matrix `matrixK`. For example it could be something like

```
matrixK = [[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14]]
```

I need to delete certain columns of the matrix, and these columns need to be chosen according to a pattern that depend on their index as columns.
In other words,

```
for i in range(number_of_columns)
    if (i satisfy a certain condtion):
        column[i] needs to be deleted.
```

and as a final result I need to get the same initial `matrixK`, deprived of the columns that satisfy the condition. What is the best pythonic way to do that?

To make an example, referring to the `matrixK` defined above as an example, let's consider

```
for i in range(5):
       if (i%2==0):
           column[i] needs to be deleted
```

which should delete columns 2 and 4.

Comment: it would have been nice to share what you've already tried. Remember that SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Condition `i%2==0` would remove column 0 as well as 2 and 4. This is because ndexing in Python (and many other computer languages) starts at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done two different ways depending on whether you need to delete the column in-place in the original matrix or can just replace it with a new one. An example of each way is shown below.
Note that neither requires every row of the matrix to be the same length.

```
# in-place removal of column in matrix

matrixK = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]

for row in matrixK:
    for i in reversed(range(len(row))):
        if i % 2 == 0:
           del row[i:i+1]

print('matrixK after: {}'.format(matrixK))
```

Or:

```
# removal of columns in matrix by recreating it

matrixK = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]

matrixK = [[row[i] for i in range(len(row)) if i % 2] for row in matrixK]

print('matrixK after: {}'.format(matrixK))
```

Both output:

```
matrixK after: [[1, 3], [6, 8], [11, 13]]
```

**More Information**

In the interests of full disclosure, please note that there's also another way to perform the column deletions that involves using the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function which is very fast.

The code isn't as readable as the other two, and only works if every row of the matrix is the same length — but it's faster than the two above.

```
matrixK = zip(*[row for i, row in enumerate(zip(*matrixK)) if i % 2])
```

Which produces:

```
matrixK after: [(1, 3), (6, 8), (11, 13)]
```

Where every row is a `tuple` rather than a `list`. If that's an problem, they can be turned into sub-lists by using:

```
matrixK = map(list, zip(*[row for i, row in enumerate(zip(*matrixK)) if i % 2]))
```

This does slow it down, but it still somewhat faster than the first two methods.

Answer (score 2):

If the length of sublists are the same you can use `zip()` function within a list comprehension like following:

```
>>> zip(*[j for i, j in enumerate(zip(*matrixK)) if i%2 != 0])
[(1, 3), (6, 8), (11, 13)]
```

Or you can use a boolean indexing numpy arrays:

```
>>> arr = np.array(matrixK)
>>> arr[:,np.arange(arr.shape[1])%2 != 0]
array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 6,  8],
       [11, 13]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `columnFlag` array to mark the columns that need to be deleted.

```
columnFlag = {}
for column in range(number_of_columns):
    if(satisfiesCondition(column)):
        columnFlag.add(column)
```

Now, you can create a `result` 2D array that has the same number of rows as `matrixK` and `len(columnFlag)` columns lesser than that of `matrixK`.

Copy over the elements from `matrixK` to `result`, only for the columns not in `columnFlag` and return the `result` array.

Answer (score 1):

```
 >>> matrixK[:] = map(lambda y : list(filter(lambda x: y.index(x)%2 != 0, y)), matrixK)
 >>> matrixK
 [[1, 3], [6, 8], [11, 13]]
```

You can change the condition inside the `lambda` function of the `filter` depending on what you actually want